Is the map $T$: $T(M): XMX^{-1} + i \dot{X}X^{-1}$ invertible?
If $T$ is a map that takes a matrix $M$ to given $T(M) = XMX^{-1} + i \dot{X}X^{-1} = N$ where matrix $X = \sqrt{Y}$ with $Y$ satisfying $i\dot{Y} = M^* Y - Y M$, where $^*$ is conjugate-transpose and $\dot{X}$ means time derivative $dX/dt$.
Question:

What can we say about invertibility of $T$? To be precise, can we find $T^{-1}$ such that $T^{-1} (N) = M$?

If $M$ linearly depends on some scalar parameters $x_1,\dots,x_n$, will $N$ also depend linearly on these parameters linearly? For example my $M$ could be
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 
       2x_1 + 3x_2 &  x_1\\
           x_1  & 3x_1 - 2x_2 
       \end{pmatrix},$$
shall $N$ always have elements that are linearly in $x_1$ and $x_2$?



What does $\dot{X}$ mean?

Time derivative.... Just edited.

First, very non-linear. Second, you’re talking about functions of $t$, so presumably your parameters are necessarily functions of $t$. This seems to be an  incredibly complicated system of  differential equations. The tags are incorrect.

@TedShifrin, I assume all $x_k's$ are time independent.
